# Specifying an index for getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

Im trying to find a way to specify an index number for the selected node *from the button* but i failed in getting the logic for it , I tried running a For loop but it'd just call all the buttons while i want the clicked button only to do the function 
HTML:

```
    <div>
            <button onclick="Change()">Change Color</button>
            <button onclick="Change()">Change Color</button>
            <button onclick="Change()">Change Color</button>
            <button onclick="Change()">Change Color</button>
            <button onclick="Change()">Change Color</button>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.ChangedColor{
    color:red;
}
```

JS:

```
function Change(){
    var y = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[y.length];
    y.classList.toggle("ChangedColor");
}
```

Im pretty sure the logic im using is wrong but i cant think of a way other than loops , Even with that , It did not work and showed an error.
Could someone tell me how to specify an index depending on which button was clicked by the user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this be of help to you?

```html
    <div>
            <button onclick="Change(this)">Change Color</button>
            <button onclick="Change(this)">Change Color</button>
            <button onclick="Change(this)">Change Color</button>
            <button onclick="Change(this)">Change Color</button>
            <button onclick="Change(this)">Change Color</button>
    </div>
```

```
function Change(ix){
  ix.classList.toggle("ChangedColor");
}
```

Comment: Oh this worked perfectly great and understandable , Thanks! , But is there a way to use a for loop in case the number of buttons/children is big ? Or do i have to write its index for each number ?

Comment: @Yishmeray in order to use this you have to put it in Change(this)

Comment: Thanks a lot again ! , It works this way pretty good 
I should have a look on how to use functions with paramaters after this

Answer (score 0):

Get the element being clicked from the event object

```js
function Change() {
  const btn = event.currentTarget;
  btn.classList.toggle("ChangedColor");
}
```

```css
.ChangedColor {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="Change()">Change Color</button>
  <button onclick="Change()">Change Color</button>
  <button onclick="Change()">Change Color</button>
  <button onclick="Change()">Change Color</button>
  <button onclick="Change()">Change Color</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice, Martin Buezas. I guess we could abstract it even further to use 'this', eh? But Yours is a tad more elegant.

Comment: @Yishmeray `this` would refer to the `window` object in that case, I guess you could re bind the `this` correctly somehow, but that would be unnecessary. A better approach to this would be to remove click attribute from every element and add event listeners entirely via javascript.

Comment: Right you are, @Martin Buezas! My focus has been on speed rather than accuracy, but as I've said a couple of times already, yours is the more elegant solution. Mine, as amended several times, also works now, but there you go. I admit to being totally unused to this native stuff after years of being spoiled by jquery. But it's good exercise!

Comment: @Yishmeray Thanks jquery for getting us through the dark ages :)

Comment: @MartinBuezas by the way it also works without using event parameter

Comment: How about that! The event object is available inside the handler without being explicitly mentioned in the calling sequence? That's a good little trick!